# R: Voronoi tesselation from long/lat data?

Tags: r, spatial-statistics, voronoi-thiessen

I want to create a SpatialPointDataFrame and Voronoi Tesselation from my .csv data downloaded from EPA, available here: http://uloz.to/xboQc7cu/no2-calif-csv

I convert my data in SPDF format in 2 ways:

```
my.tab<-read.csv("no2_calif.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = "")
coordinates(my.tab) <- ~ Longitude + Latitude
```

or

```
my.tab<-read.csv("no2_calif.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = "")
my.tab.spdf<- SpatialPointsDataFrame(cbind(my.tab$Longitude, my.tab$Latitude), my.tab)
```

and use Voronoi tesselation published here: http://carsonfarmer.com/2009/09/voronoi-polygons-with-r/

```
voronoipolygons = function(layer) {
    require(deldir)
    crds = layer@coords
    z = deldir(crds[,1], crds[,2])
    w = tile.list(z)
    polys = vector(mode='list', length=length(w))
    require(sp)
    for (i in seq(along=polys)) {
        pcrds = cbind(w[[i]]$x, w[[i]]$y)
        pcrds = rbind(pcrds, pcrds[1,])
        polys[[i]] = Polygons(list(Polygon(pcrds)), ID=as.character(i))
    }
    SP = SpatialPolygons(polys)
    voronoi = SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(SP, data=data.frame(x=crds[,1], 
        y=crds[,2], row.names=sapply(slot(SP, 'polygons'), 
        function(x) slot(x, 'ID'))))
}
```

Using either

my.tab.voro <-voronoipolygons(my.tab)

or

```
my.tab.spdf.voro <-voronoipolygons(my.tab.spdf)
```

I obtain back the error:

```
 Error in data.frame(x = crds[, 1], y = crds[, 2], row.names = sapply(slot(SP,  : 
  row names supplied are of the wrong length
```

Please, where the problem could be? do I need to have my coordinates in XY format? if yes, please, how? just reproject my data?

Comment: just give it dummy data voronoi = SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(SP, data=data.frame(x = seq(length(SP))))  or do return(SP) and work with that instead - it's got nothing to do with the coordinate system. If you make a reproducible example someone might fix it.

Comment: thank you @mdsumner but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reproducible example, just fix the script to make a dummy data.frame.

```
voronoipolygons = function(layer) {
require(deldir)
crds = layer@coords
z = deldir(crds[,1], crds[,2])
w = tile.list(z)
polys = vector(mode='list', length=length(w))
require(sp)
for (i in seq(along=polys)) {
    pcrds = cbind(w[[i]]$x, w[[i]]$y)
    pcrds = rbind(pcrds, pcrds[1,])
    polys[[i]] = Polygons(list(Polygon(pcrds)), ID=as.character(i))
}
SP = SpatialPolygons(polys)
 voronoi = SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(SP, data=data.frame(dummy = seq(length(SP)), row.names=sapply(slot(SP, 'polygons'), 
    function(x) slot(x, 'ID'))))
}

library(sp)
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) <- c("x", "y")

vp <- voronoipolygons(meuse)

plot(vp)
```